# How to make customActionBar transparent and change its text colour?

Tags: java, android, css, android-actionbar

I want to make the ActionBar transparent throughout the app and also change the text colour to white in the ActionBar. I tried setting the `android:background` to `null` but it had no effect. I am still getting a white ActionBar with Black text in the following code:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_white</item>
        <!--item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <!--item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item-->
        <item name="colorAccent">#1da1f2</item>

<!--        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>-->
<!--        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>-->

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="background">@null</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/mukta_bold</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/app_white</item>

    </style>

<!--    <style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"-->
<!--        parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">-->
<!--        <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_light_black</item>-->
<!--    </style>-->

    <style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Switch_Style">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.MyButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: You comment two lines which reference MyActionBar, uncomment them and try again

Comment: If I uncomment it then the text becomes white but the action bar still remains white and not transparent

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? You need to have some background color in order to show white colored text.

Comment: Yeah I have that background colour set already, I just want the ActionBar to be transparent/merge with the background colour.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `colorControlNormal` flag in your Theme for AppBar

```
<style name="appBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and in your `AppBarLayout` use background as transparent

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/appBarTheme">
    ...........
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

Make your BaseTheme of app as `NoActionBar` so you can create a custom action bar in your activity/fragment -

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Happy Coding !!

Comment: where should I use the `AppBarLayout` para of your code? And do I need to remove anything from my code after writing yours?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly,  basic idea is we are not using default app bar instead we are creating a CustomAppBar by adding `AppBarLayout` in activity/fragment ...

Comment: Actually its quite a big project and I have a lot of layouts and activities, I also call the support action bar multiple times in the activities itself to set some text on it so I don't think using the layout everytime would be feasible for me. You can see the entire codebase here https://github.com/tavlab-iiitd/WashKaro

Comment: hmm... agreed, I'll check and let know if I would find something which can be applied without much hustle ....

Comment: That would be really helpful, please do. Thanks a lot!!